# When we use "Delete Element" on Google Chrome Developer tools, then does it really delete that element from the live global servers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, element

Well, when we open the Google Chrome browser and use the "Developer options" panel, then if we select some webpage page code in the "elements" tab and select the "Delete element" option from the right-menu, then does it deletes that element from the live global servers or it deletes just on my browser?

I am complete newbie in the world of HTML or programming. I don't know anything about servers.

[image]

Comment: Just your own browser obviously. It would be a massive security hole if you could just go about deleting parts of other people's websites.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that I deleted something..haha

Answer (score 2):

Your browser contains a copy of a page on the server*, and that's what's deleted from. No data is deleted from the server.

It would be ridiculously flawed if users could delete data from the server via the developer tools. That also wouldn't make sense in many cases since many webpages are generated as needed. They don't exist until they're requested, so there wouldn't be anything to delete. Elements are also often generated by JavaScript on the client end, so again there would be nothing corresponding on the server to delete.

`*` In the cases where the page is delivered directly and not generated by a server side language.